# Android library using old Ktor version causes NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, kotlin, noclassdeffounderror, ktor, ktor-client

I'm trying to add TelemetryDeck analytics to my Android app that uses Ktor 2.0.0 but I get an error when I launch the app because TelemetryDeck's SDK uses Ktor 1.6.7

The Full Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/ktor/client/features/HttpClientFeature;
                    at com.telemetrydeck.sdk.TelemetryClient.<init>(TelemetryClient.kt:18)
                    at com.telemetrydeck.sdk.TelemetryManager.send-gIAlu-s(TelemetryManager.kt:74)
                    at com.telemetrydeck.sdk.TelemetryBroadcastTimer$start$1$1.invokeSuspend(TelemetryBroadcastTimer.kt:48)
                    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:100)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
                    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@b96a820, Dispatchers.IO]
                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.ktor.client.features.HttpClientFeature" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.mmm.example.debug/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes10.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~3WLnofo17mW-pHZeEjjPaA==/com.mmm.example.debug-BXbaTkrc1DYfN-kyN2QXsg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~3WLnofo17mW-pHZeEjjPaA==/com.mmm.example.debug-BXbaTkrc1DYfN-kyN2QXsg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~3WLnofo17mW-pHZeEjjPaA==/com.mmm.example.debug-BXbaTkrc1DYfN-kyN2QXsg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
                    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                    ... 11 more
```

Is there a way to fix it or I have to wait until they release a new version that uses Ktor 2.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue updating a java project from jdk 12 to 17. In my case I had to lift the corresponding library as well to fix the error.

But normally this is caused when there is a class file that your code depends on and it is present at compile time but not found at runtime. Have you looked for differences in your build time and runtime classpaths?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).